# How do I define var i based on which check box is checked?

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I'm trying to make a to do list that you can check off completed task and it would calculate the percentage done. So the first thing I tried was making a couple of checkboxes and adding an event listener for the click then I'll check the value probably to see if it is = `true` or something like that.

I'm trying to figure out a way to define `var i` if I click on the first checkbox I want it to be set to 0 and the second set to 1. But I want it to dynamically set the `var i` because the user will be adding new checkboxes and I can't declare what `i` equals after they add a new item. Anyway this is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var list;
    var checkboxes;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",load);
    function load(){
        list = get("list");
        checkboxes = getTag("input");
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click",toggle);
    }
    function toggle(){
        alert(this.value);
    }
    function get(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    function getTag(tag){
        return document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Kung Fu To Do List 1.0</h1>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="true"></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Colin for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not sure what you mean by defining `i`. But it seems like what you're looking for is calculating the percentage complete, and keeping that updated when/if the user adds new items. I wouldn't keep track of `checkboxes` but instead loop over them when you need to calculate. Further, having a method that adds new checkboxes for you can then hook in the events you want to monitor. Something like: (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nuuyx/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <script>
        var list;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",load);
        function load(){
            list = get("list");
            checkboxes = getTag("input");
            for(var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++){
                checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", toggle);
            }
            updatePercentage();
        }
        function updatePercentage(){
            var checkboxes = getTag("input");
            var total = checkboxes.length;
            var done = 0;
            for(var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++){
                if(checkboxes[i].checked){
                    done++;    
                }
            }
            get('percent').innerHTML = 'Done: '+Math.round((done/total)*100)+'%';
        }
        function newCheckbox(){
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            var chk = document.createElement('input');
            chk.type = 'checkbox';
            chk.addEventListener("click", toggle);
            item.appendChild(chk);
            list.appendChild(item);
            updatePercentage();
        }
        function toggle(){
            //alert(this.value);
            updatePercentage();
        }
        function get(id){
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
        function getTag(tag){
            return document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Kung Fu To Do List 1.0</h1>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="true"></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="percent"></div>
    <button onclick="newCheckbox()">new item</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want (at least what I think is what you want) is to create `<input type="hidden" value="-1" />`. Its value would be changed in your onClick event. You can name your checkboxes (0, 1, 2, ...) and read this variable in event then save it to hidden input field.